# Customize Validation Messages in Laravel Requests

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do i customize my Validation Messages in My REQUESTS FILE?

how do i add messages next to the rules?
What i want is to put customized messages just like the common validation. Is it possible? to do just the normal way of validation in the Requests?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class ArticleRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
        'title' => 'required|min:5',
        'content' =>'required',
        'user_id' => 'required|numeric',
        'category_id' => 'required|numeric',
        'published_at' => 'required|date'
        ];
    }
```

}

Answer (score 9):

You can define a `messages()` method with validation rules for that form request only:

```
class StoreArticleRequest extends Request
{
    //

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required' => 'The title is required.',
            'category_id.numeric' => 'Invalid category value.',
        ];
    }
}
```

It takes the form of the field name and the rule name, with a dot in between, i.e. `field.rule`.

Comment: you can create this custom request message via command line : 
"php artisan make:request StoreArticleRequest"

the StoreArticleRequest.php class is located on app/Http/Requests directory.

Comment: @sagor Right… Nothing to do with the question (or answer) though.

Answer (score 4):

> You may customize the error messages used by the form request by
>   overriding the messages method. This method should return an array of
>   attribute / rule pairs and their corresponding error messages:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title.required' => 'A title is required',
        'body.required'  => 'A message is required',
    ];
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution to translate the field labels:

```
...

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
       'title' => 'required|min:5',
       'content' =>'required',
       'user_id' => 'required|numeric',
       'category_id' => 'required|numeric',
       'published_at' => 'required|date'
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the validation attributes that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function attributes()
{
    return [
        'title' => __('app.title'),
        'content' => __('app.content'),
        'user_id' => __('app.user'),
        'category_id' => __('app.category'),
        'published_at' => __('app.published_at')
    ];
}
```